# How to auto deploy GitLab repository to Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gitlab, nuxt.js, gitlab-ci

I have a Nuxt application that is running in a repository in Google Cloud Platform, that uses App Engine.

To deploy it, I:

1. Get in Google Cloud Platform Console
2. cd to my repo folder
3. git pull changes in default branch
4. log in with an authenticated user
5. run the command `npm run generate` (I use generate because I have this article for full static [Nuxt-full static](https://nuxtjs.org/announcements/going-full-static/)
6. And finally run gcloud app deploy app.yaml --project **project_id**

**app.yaml** configuration:

```
    runtime: nodejs12

instance_class: F2

handlers:
  - url: /_nuxt
    static_dir: .nuxt/dist/client
    secure: always

  - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt))$
    static_files: static/\1
    upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt)$
    secure: always

  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always

env_variables:
  HOST: '0.0.0.0'
```

Google Cloud Platform and Gitlab documentation about CI/CD look outdated.

How can I configure an CI/CD (`.gitlab-ci.yml`) file in my *master branch* for when I update this branch, update my App Engine application and make a new build for it?

Comment: You may have a look at this [documentation](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/automated-ci-cd-deployment-to-app-engine-with-cloud-build/). Let me know if that helps!

Comment: I will look it right now! Hold on, and thanks for helping! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Gitlab as a self-hosted version, You can make CI/CD pipeline that automates your everyday manual deployments.

First, Install npm package and gcloud SDK in your Gitlab instance.

Second, Edit your CI/CD Pipeline as you described. It can be helpful if you use CI/CD Pipeline editor, GitLab provides.

ex: My .gitlab-ci.yml contents here. It's just one step, but you can have many of it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With GitLab 15.5 (Oct. 2022), you can also checkout:

> ### [Deploy apps to Google Cloud with GitLab Cloud Seed](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/10/22/gitlab-15-5-released/#deploy-apps-to-google-cloud-with-gitlab-cloud-seed)
>
> Cloud Seed allows GitLab and Google Cloud customers to migrate to the cloud using a single platform, consolidating their tech stack without slowing down their cloud adoption process.
>
> Cloud Seed is built into the GitLab web UI and leverages CI/CD pipeline capabilities. It is specifically tailored to offer a frictionless developer experience for consuming Google Cloud services, supporting [Service Accounts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/cloud_seed/index.html#set-up-deployment-credentials), [Cloud Run](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/cloud_seed/index.html#deploy-to-google-cloud-run), and [Cloud SQL](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/cloud_seed/index.html#provision-cloud-sql-databases).
>
> To develop this capability, GitLab worked with Google Cloud to build best-in-class experiences to simplify, automate and thus accelerate cloud resource provisioning, deployment automation and configuration. Google Cloud and GitLab worked together in an open-source model to make Cloud Seed available for paid and free users.
>
> Cloud Seed’s easy-to-use and accessible format drives organic cloud adoption amongst users. Since it is a frictionless, open-source tool, developers and product teams can consume the Google Cloud services complementing its leadership’s cloud adoption efforts leading to an organic company-wide shift. As a result, GitLab is seeing increased bottom-up adoption of cloud services.

See:

- [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/cloud_seed/index.html)
- [Accelerate cloud adoption with GitLab's open source partnership with Google Cloud](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2022/10/11/accelerate-cloud-adoption-with-gitlabs-open-source-partnership-with-google-cloud/)
- [Issue Board](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/five-minute-production/-/boards)